# Overlay div background image on underlying content image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to hide an image/ `i` tag inside a wrapper div when a background image of the wrapper div is present. Basically inside the wrapper div there is an icon for times when there is no image in the background of the wrapper div. But when there will be a background image set to the wrapper div the background image should overlap and hence hide the icon inside the div.

My problem is that both the icon and div background colour is being shown together.

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-fluid rounded-circle avatar">
    <i class="material-icons icon">account_circle</i>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.avatar {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid cadetblue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.icon {
}
```

Comment: ZIndex could be a solution

Comment: Not working. Tried already

Comment: How are you toggling the background image. Is it binded to an event? @Ayan. I don't think it is possible with the current structure.

Comment: Currently its not binded, am testing with changing the css of the wrapper by setting `background-image`. If it is not possible with the current structure, please feel free to guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You possibly *can't* set it up such that the `i` element is *behind* the `background-image`. But you can do this - if you know when `background-image` is there and when there isn't you can decide to hide the `i` element *behind* its parent element using `z-index`.

See a demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.avatar {
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.bck-image {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/50x50");
}

.img-fluid.avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.my-icon-hidden .icon {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="wrapper">
  With background image
  <div class="img-fluid rounded-circle avatar bck-image">
    <i class="material-icons icon">account_circle</i>
  </div><br/>z-index: -1
  <div class="img-fluid rounded-circle avatar my-icon-hidden bck-image">
    <i class="material-icons icon">account_circle</i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  No background image
  <div class="img-fluid rounded-circle avatar">
    <i class="material-icons icon">account_circle</i>
  </div><br/>z-index: -1
  <div class="img-fluid rounded-circle avatar my-icon-hidden">
    <i class="material-icons icon">account_circle</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the image is in the `img` element, you can *position* the image above the `i` *absolutely* - so if the `img` element is not there, the icon will show - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.avatar {
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.img-fluid.avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.avatar i, .avatar img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.avatar i {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.avatar img {
  z-index: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="wrapper">
  Without img element
  <div class="img-fluid rounded-circle avatar">
    <i class="material-icons icon">account_circle</i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  With img element
  <div class="img-fluid rounded-circle avatar">
    <i class="material-icons icon">account_circle</i>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if instead of `i` tag there is an image tag?

Comment: kindly see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ayan/jdukLs4u/4/ . Let me know whether its a proper way.

Comment: that's fine if you want to bring the child element (`img`) *above* the parent element...

Comment: Thank you for all the help, wish I could accept both of your answers. I learned new lessons. :)

Comment: maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255880/opacity-of-div-creates-unexpected-results-and-blends-content-with-image/41255988#41255988) will be a good read too, thanks!

Comment: Concise, informative and definitely a good read. Thanks again. :) I will keep these in mind while dealing with the z-axis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo element, here `::after`, for the background image, which will cover any child element when present, no matter if it is an `i` or an `img`.

```css
.avatar {
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
.avatar::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: inherit;                  /* added to prevent overflow  */
  overflow: hidden;                        /* added to prevent overflow  */
}
.bck-image::after {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100/f00");
}
.img-fluid.avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="img-fluid rounded-circle avatar bck-image">
  <i class="material-icons icon">account_circle</i>
</div>


<div class="img-fluid rounded-circle avatar">
  <i class="material-icons icon">account_circle</i>
</div>
```

Comment: ok! Btw I tried a small fiddle and somehow it worked out without using any extra markup or pseudo elements. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ayan/jdukLs4u/4/ . Comment out the background image to see it work.

Comment: @Ayan You can do like that too :) as long as you dont need a background color

Comment: @Ayan Also do note, using `z-index` can cause other issues, which mine doesn't

Comment: Alright. Can you mention the issues for me and others for future reference?

Comment: Btw the red background image goes out of the div. I think a `overflow: hidden` should solve it. Right?

Comment: @Ayan This article has a good explanation what/how `z-index` works, https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/ , which is way better to understand, so you _know_ what is going on and can avoid such issues. By using a non `z-index` solution you don't have to worry.

Comment: @Ayan About overflow, I updated my answer (see notes in CSS)

Comment: there is no issue with using `z-index` unless you use it without understanding *how* it works... :)

Comment: @kukkuz That's why I added a link and saying just that in a comment above :)

Comment: @Ayan If you can avoid using `z-index` (change the default stacking) and use elements natural stacking context, I recommend you do.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, wish I could accept both of your answers. I learned new lessons. :)