# HTML form input elements visually positioned outside form

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox, position

I have container with height set to 0 which contains form.

```
<div class="container">
    <div role="button" data-define="show.element">show register form</div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
      <div class="box">
        <form>
          <input class="form-element" type="text" name="login" placeholder="login"/>
          <input class="form-element" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <input class="form-element-submit" type="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What I want to achieve, is form sliding out of "box-wrapper" element (which initially has display property `visibility` set to `hidden`) after clicking button with "show register form" text. On click I'm adding css class which changes box element height and sets property visibility of box-wrapper element to "visible". However form input elements are "sliding" out not from box-wrapper element as I intented, they seems to have be initially placed at top of "container" element. Here is my CSS code:

```
body {
  background: #34495E;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: #191919;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
div[data-define="show.element"] {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  outline: none;
}
div[data-define="show.element"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #2ECC71;
}
div[data-define="show.element"]:active {
  transform: translatey(2px);
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  transition: 1s;

  &-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    visibility: hidden;

    &-visible {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
  &-active {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
form {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.form-element {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 150px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: width 0.25s;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;

  &-submit {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 150px;
    background: none;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    outline: none;
  }
}
.form-element:focus {
  width: 250px;
  border-color: #2ECC71;
}
.form-element-submit:hover {
  background: #2ECC71;
}
```

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/Furmanus/pen/oVqKJG?editors=0100

What I did wrong? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make body relative. Add z-index and background property to show.element button. Set box height to maybe 20px so that box-wrapper seems to originate from show.element button.

```
body {
  background: #34495E;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -12.5%;
    background: #191919;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
div[data-define="show.element"] {
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    background: #191919;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    transition: 0.1s;
    outline: none;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Updated codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QorQrj?editors=0100

**EDIT -** Ah like @kukkuz mentioned, justify-content was the problem. When the height of parent is 0 but justify-content is center. It tries to vertically center the child elements whose heights are greater than 0 and ends up going above to vertically center on a parent whose height is 0.

Removing justify-content will position your input elements the way you desire but there is a problem with slide animation because the input elements stay where they are supposed to and the transition makes no difference because these elements arent affected.

So set, margin, border, height, padding of input elements to 0 by default. And on click of "show register form", update these properties to what they are supposed to be.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QorQrj?editors=0100

Comment: Ok obviously it works, but I still don't understand why inputs appear on top of container element with class "container" - could you please explain that to me?

Comment: They seem to appear within the container but above "Show Register Form" button.

Comment: Yes I already figured that out, they appear above show register form, which is BEYOND parent form element, and even beyond element <div class="box-wrapper">. My question was, what's the reason of such behavior (primarily, obviously I don't understand something here) and how to fix this.

Comment: That was explanation and solution I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is bring the `button` above the `box-wrapper` in the stacking context using `z-index`. So add `z-index: 1` to the `button` - since `z-index` works only on *positioned elements* (element should not have *static* position) now it will work. You can read more about [`z-index and stacking context here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255880/opacity-of-div-creates-unexpected-results-and-blends-content-with-image/41255988#41255988).

Now add a *background* to the `button` so that we can visually understand the depth - see demo below and [`updated codepen`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYVKvo?editors=0100):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('div[role="button"]');
const submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
const boxWrapper = document.querySelector('.box-wrapper');
let isVisible = false;

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (isVisible) {
    box.classList.remove('box-active');
    boxWrapper.classList.remove('box-wrapper-visible');
    isVisible = false;
  } else {
    box.classList.add('box-active');
    boxWrapper.classList.add('box-wrapper-visible');
    isVisible = true;
  }
});
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #34495E;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: #191919;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
div[data-define="show.element"] {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #191919; /* background added */
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  outline: none;
  position: relative; /* positioned the element */
  z-index: 1; /* added z-index */
}
div[data-define="show.element"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #2ECC71;
}
div[data-define="show.element"]:active {
  transform: translatey(2px);
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  transition: 1s;
}
.box-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.box-wrapper-visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
.box-active {
  height: 300px;
}
form {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.form-element {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 150px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: width 0.25s;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
}
.form-element-submit {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 150px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  outline: none;
}
.form-element:focus {
  width: 250px;
  border-color: #2ECC71;
}
.form-element-submit:hover {
  background: #2ECC71;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div role="button" data-define="show.element">show register form</div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
      <div class="box">
        <form>
          <input class="form-element" type="text" name="login" placeholder="login"/>
          <input class="form-element" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <input class="form-element-submit" type="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

To address the problem of the form element placed at the top of the `container` rather than from the top of `box-wrapper` - see what happens when I add a `min-height: 0` to the `input` elements:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('div[role="button"]');
const submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
const boxWrapper = document.querySelector('.box-wrapper');
let isVisible = false;

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (isVisible) {
    box.classList.remove('box-active');
    boxWrapper.classList.remove('box-wrapper-visible');
    isVisible = false;
  } else {
    box.classList.add('box-active');
    boxWrapper.classList.add('box-wrapper-visible');
    isVisible = true;
  }
});
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #34495E;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: #191919;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
div[data-define="show.element"] {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #191919; /* background added */
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  outline: none;
  position: relative; /* positioned the element */
  z-index: 1; /* added z-index */
}
div[data-define="show.element"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #2ECC71;
}
div[data-define="show.element"]:active {
  transform: translatey(2px);
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  transition: 1s;
}
.box-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.box-wrapper-visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
.box-active {
  height: 300px;
}
form {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.form-element {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 150px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: width 0.25s;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  min-height: 0; /* added */
}
.form-element-submit {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 150px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  outline: none;
}
.form-element:focus {
  width: 250px;
  border-color: #2ECC71;
}
.form-element-submit:hover {
  background: #2ECC71;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div role="button" data-define="show.element">show register form</div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
      <div class="box">
        <form>
          <input class="form-element" type="text" name="login" placeholder="login"/>
          <input class="form-element" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <input class="form-element-submit" type="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The issue is clearly due to the default `min-height: auto` for a *column flexbox* - *flex items* take a minimum space as much as their content in the flex direction.

And another reason for a slight shift toward the top is because you have `justify-content: center` for your `form` element.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how it solves my problem. Problem was, that form input elements, appear to be visually placed at the top of  <div class="container"> (it can be seen even when I inspect those element in chrome dev tools), despite the fact, they their direct parent element if form, which has different placement on page. I don't understand what's the reason of such weird behavior. What I want to achieve is form element "sliding" from top of element <div class="box-wrapper">. Your updated codepen doesn't solve that, as I don't really see difference between my version.

Comment: @Furman found the issue - try add `min-height: 0` for your flex items (`input` elements) and removing `justify-content: center` that shifts your `form` upwards while center aligning in a zero height container...